# WPF: Zoom user control animation

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have created a user control:

```
<UserControl ...>
  <Grid DataContext="{Binding UserContrlViewModel>
    <Grid Width="200" Height="100" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
      <Grid.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="zoomIn">
          <DoubleAnimation 
              Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleTransform.ScaleX" 
              From="0" 
              To="1" 
              Duration="0:0:1" /> 
          <DoubleAnimation 
              Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleTransform.ScaleY" 
              From="0"        
              To="1" 
              Duration="0:0:1" />
        </Storyboard>
      </Grid.Resources>
      <Grid.RenderTransform>
        <ScaleTransform />
      </Grid.RenderTransform>
      <Grid.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Grid">
          <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsActive}" Value="True">
              <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                  <StaticResource ResourceKey="zoomIn" />
                </BeginStoryboard>
              </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            </DataTrigger>
          </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
      </Grid.Style>

      <TextBlock Width="60" Text="Input" />
      <TextBox Width="80" Margin="80,0,0,0" />

    </Grid>
    ...
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

What I want to achieve is that when `IsActive` property of the user control's view model class is set to `true`, the `zoomIn` animation is run. This animation is supposed to zoom in the grid with it's content inside. When I trigger the animation, I get the following error message:

> Cannot resolve all property references in the property path 'ScaleTransform.ScaleX'. Verify that applicable objects support the properties.

What is wrong with my animation? How should I implement the described zoom in animation? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it:

- `<ScaleTransform>` should have `<ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.5" ScaleY="0.5" />` properties 
  set in order to make the zoom start from 50%, for example.
- In the first `<DoubleAnimation>` the value of the `Storyboard.TargetProperty` property 
  should be changed from `"ScaleTransform.ScaleX"` to `"RenderTransform.ScaleX"`.
- In the second `<DoubleAnimation>` the value of the `Storyboard.TargetProperty` property 
  should be changed from `"ScaleTransform.ScaleY"` to `"RenderTransform.ScaleY"`.